# Can't print data from a two dimensional array to an output file in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, file, fstream

At the moment this program reads data from a .pgm picture file and then prints it to another .pgm output file. However I cannot get the output function to work. The output.pgm file is still blank. It compiles, and if I add cout statements in the input loop it shows that the array is holding the data, but if I put a cout statement in the output loop it doesn't print anything. I assume this is an issue with passing the array to the outofArray function, but for the life of me I can't put my finger on it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

//the maximum size of the photo to be stored in the array
const int rows = 512;
const int columns = 512;

//the multidimensional array's row value has to be passed as a parameter.
//the intoArray function opens the input file (a .pgm file), reads the amount of rows and columns,
//then reads the pixel data into a 512x512 array and closes the input filestream
void intoArray (int argc, char* argv[], int photoArray[][columns], int &inputRows, int &inputColumns, int rows);

//this function prints the data from the picture array into the output file
void outofArray (int argc, char* argv[], int photoArray[][columns], int inputRows, int inputColumns, int rows);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int photoArray[rows][columns];
    int inputRows, inputColumns;

    if (argc != 3) {
        cout<<"Error: Incorrect number of parameters. "<<endl;
        return -1;
    }


    intoArray (argc, argv, photoArray, inputRows, inputColumns, rows);
    outofArray (argc, argv, photoArray, inputRows, inputColumns, rows);

    //just testing for proper fileread (this also does not print anything for some reason)
    cout<<"rows: "<<inputRows<<endl
        <<"columns: "<<inputColumns<<endl;

    return 0;
}

void intoArray (int argc, char *argv[], int photoArray[][columns], int &inputRows, int &inputColumns, int rows) {
    ifstream pgmIn;
    string p2;
    int twofivefive, i, j;

    if (argc != 3)
        cout<<"Error: Incorrect number of parameters. "<<endl;

    //open the input filestream
    pgmIn.open(argv[1]);

    //check if file opened properly
    if (pgmIn.fail()) {
        perror (argv[1]);
    }

    //read the initial data from the pgm file. the p2 and twofivefive variables
    //can be ignored, as they are not needed, but need to be read in order to get to the
    //actual picture data.
    while (pgmIn>>p2>>inputColumns>>inputRows>>twofivefive) {

        //once again just checking for proper fileread.
        //i'm not sure what i did, but before the function became impossible to call,
        //only the p2 string was being read and it printed just fine, but the rest of
        //the values were never read.
        cout<<p2<<" "<<endl<<inputColumns<<" "<<inputRows<<" "<<endl<<twofivefive<<endl;

            //this actually reads the picture data into the array.
            for (i = 0; i < inputRows; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < inputColumns; i++) {
                    pgmIn>>photoArray[i][j];
                    //I put a cout statement here followed by a cout.flush() and it printed the data entries
                    //just fine, so I assume it is properly reading the file
                }
            }
        }

    pgmIn.close();
}

void outofArray (int argc, char* argv[], int photoArray[][columns], int inputRows, int inputColumns, int rows) {
    ofstream pgmOut;
    int i, j;

    if (argc != 3)
            cout<<"Error: Incorrect number of parameters. "<<endl;

    //open the output filestream
    pgmOut.open(argv[2]);

    //check if file opened properly
    if (pgmOut.fail())
        perror (argv[2]);

    //prints the necessary data for the .pgm file to be read
    pgmOut<<"P2"<<endl<<inputColumns<<" "<<inputRows<<endl<<"255"<<endl;

    //prints data to output file
    for(i = 0; i < inputRows; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < inputColumns; i++) {
            pgmOut<<photoArray[i][j]<<" ";
            //if I put a cout statement here as I did in the previous function,
            //it doesn't print anything. This leads me to believe that there is an
            //issue with passing my array and its contents to this function
        }
    }

    pgmOut.close();
}
```

Comment: Don't pass the raw command line arguments around. Parse them into some info struct of your own and pass that around instead. Avoid endl in files as it's slow. Use "\n" instead unless you have a special need to flush the file more often.

Comment: Avoiding `endl` is a valid optimization strategy, once you know that you have a performance problem, but it makes debugging harder.  In general, unless you really know what you're doing, you should use `endl` as the default.

Comment: Note that you have > 1 MB of data on the stack - that's fine for most desktop/server operating systems these days, but you don't mention what environment you're using, so if it's something with a smaller default stack size (e.g. an embedded app) then you may run into a stack overflow situation.

Comment: @JamesKanze Disagree. Unless your program is crashing and you need every character. It's better to flush after a series of small writes with many new lines. I've seen pathological cases written by people who didn't know that endl also flushes. endl is a terrible invention.

Comment: @NeilKirk It simulates the otherwise missing "line buffered" in C.  It's a useful compromise between unbuffered and fully buffered.  Using `'\n'` instead of `std::endl` is simply premature optimization in most cases.

Comment: @JamesKanze Assume that endl didn't exist and the only way to replicate it was `<< "\n" << std::flush`. Would you write that every time? Would tutorials tell beginners to do that? People should decide whether to flush every line or not based on a real decision, not just the default of the language.

Comment: @NeilKirk You've just argued in favor of my point.  The reason `std::endl` exists is because that's what you usually want, and you don't want to have to write `'\n' << std::flush` every time to get it.  The library was designed with typical the typical use case for the naive user in mind.

Comment: @JamesKanze Ok I accept your point. My background is writing number crunchers that output tons of data running overnight, so perhaps that has corrupted my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely your error.

You have

```
            for (j = 0; j < inputColumns; i++) {
```

You need

```
            for (j = 0; j < inputColumns; j++) {
                                       // ^^^^ j, not i.
```

This error exists in `intoArray` and `outofArray`.

Comment: Well that's embarrassing. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't feel too bad. Most of us have been through such embarrassing moments.